# Mockito on ClassA, mock modifying state of ClassB

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito

I have an object say AClazz, which contains another object BClazz. When a method is invoked on AClazz, it mocks altering the state of BClazz.

```
class AClazz(){
  BClazz b;
  public void begin(){
     b.start();
  }
}

class BClazz{
  private boolean running = false;

  public void start(){
         running = true;
  }
  public boolean isRunning(){
        return running;
   }
}
```

I want to write unit tests on class AClazz - to test that when begin() is invoked, the state of BClazz is set accordingly. BClazz should not actually be invoked, but the behaviour of method isRunning() will be mocked

```
  AClazz a;
  BClazz b; 
  // inject b into a

  // Mockito.when(a.begin( (//should invoke b.start())) ) such that b.isRunning() returns true
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A test in AClazz using a mock of BClazz can verify that, when you call `a.begin()`, `b.start()` has been invoked.  `b` is a mock, not a real thing, so I am not aware that it's possible to inspect it further (and I don't think you should, even if you could).

A test in BClazz can then be written to verify that, when `b.start()` has been invoked, `b.running` is indeed true.  No mocks are needed here.

Between the two tests, you will have covered the required behaviours.  AClazz does not need to know what BClazz does when it is told to start, in accordance with good object oriented design, so there is no reason to write tests in AClazz to check the value of `b.running`.

Result: good tests, good object segregation, good programmer :)

---

Expanding answer in response to comment:

```
@Test
void shouldTriggerCorrectResponseWhenBClazzStartReturnsTrue() {
  when(mockOfBClazz.start()).thenReturn(true);
  a.begin();
  // some code to assert that a has done the right thing
  // in response to a hypothetical 'true' result from mockOfBClazz
}

@Test
void shouldTriggerCorrectResponseWhenBClazzStartReturnsFalse() {
  when(mockOfBClazz.start()).thenReturn(false);
  a.begin();
  // some code to assert that a has done the right thing
  //in response to a hypothetical 'false' result from mockOfBClazz
}
```

You can use the when(mock.method()).thenReturn(response) to tell your test class what to use as the return value from a mocked class, so you have lots of control over testing every edge case you can think of.

Comment: What about the case when on : call method1 on ClazzA, mock behavior such that method2 then returns true. Also call method2 on ClassA, method2 returns false

Comment: Good question!  See the expanded answer, hopefully that covers it but if not then keep asking.